# Using a Producer Method To Choose a Bean Implementation

Tags: interface, cdi, producer

I followed the example on [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhpy.html) for dynamically selecting the implementation to inject during run time. I then try to implement it based on my understanding but my code always return the default implementation;

Here is my code

```
@Stateless
public class MemberRegistration {

    @Inject
    private Logger log;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    private Event<Member> memberEventSrc;

    @Inject
    @Switch
    IHandler handler;

    private int handlerValue;


    public String testCDI(int value) {

        handlerValue = value;
        log.info("handling " + value);
        log.info("handling " + handlerValue);
        return handler.handle();
    }

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    @Switch
    public IHandler produceHandler(@New Handler0 handler0,
            @New Handler1 handler1) {
        log.info("Calling producer method with handler: "+handlerValue);
        switch (handlerValue) {
            case 1:
                log.info("returning one");
                return handler1;
            case 0:
                log.info("returning 0");
                return handler0;
            default:
                log.info("returning default");
                return handler1;
        }
    }
}
```

When i call the method `testCDI` I then update the `handlerValue` so that my producer method can use that value.  What am I missing here to ensure that the producer method is called when the right value is available?

The code is running on Wildfly 8.2.0

Answer (score 0):

The instance injected isn't going to be resolved when you call the method, but at the time of injection of the bean (the stateless session bean in this case).  As a result, handlerValue will be 0.

You can however use an `Instance<IHandler>` to defer the injection.  Use an annotation literal instead of your switch to do something like

```
@Inject
@Any
private Instance<IHandler> handlerInst
```

Then in your code

```
IHandler handler = handlerInst.select(new SwitchLiteral(value)).get();
```

then do work against that guy, but in your producer you need to use the `InjectionPoint` class to read the `Switch` annotation represented by the `SwitchLiteral`

Answer (score 0):

You are running into cycling dependency here with your simplified code. Fields injected with plain `@Inject` need to be resolved BEFORE `MemberRegistration` is created, but handler field can only be created with a producer method AFTER `MemberRegistration` is created (beans with producer methods are created according to same rules as other CDI beans).

There are 2 solutions:

1. Either you create a separate `HandlerProducer` class, which will contain `produceHandler()` method and **also** `handlerValue` field. You should mark the class as `@ApplicationScoped` in order to reuse the same instance all over.
2. Or you need not only to produce IHandler dynamically, but also use (inject it) dynamically only when really needed in the `MemberRegistration` - this way handler is produced not BEFORE `MemberRegistration` is created, but after or never if not required. You do this by injecting Instance object and then use its get() method to retrieve handler when needed. Anyway, I am not sure if CDI will create a new instance every time, or reuse existing EJB. Scopes of EJBs and plain CDI beans are completely different and in general, I would not use an EJB as a bean with producer methods. It is better to always create a separate bean for producer methods, as in solution 1.

Example for solution 2 follows:

```
@Inject
@Switch
Instance<IHandler> handlerInjector;

private int handlerValue;

public String testCDI(int value) {
    handlerValue = value;
    log.info("handling " + value);
    log.info("handling " + handlerValue);
    return handlerInjector.get().handle();
}
```

Comment: Since he's using a stateless session bean, you have no guarantee that the one doing the produces is the same one that has the injection point.  As a result, you can't assume shared state.